# Centering images with URL

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am centering an image using bootstrap's center-block class.

```
<section class="container">
    <a href="www.apple.com">
    <img class="center-block" src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201605191653" width="150px;" height="100px;"/>
    </a>
</section>
```

The only problem is that the links spans the width of the container.  How do I restrict the URL to the image?

Working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bmd9ajhv/)

Comment: I don't see any url in your fiddle extending

Comment: The URL spans the width of the container.  I want to restrict it to the image itself.

Comment: I don't understand what the URL has to do with the width.

Comment: I want someone to be able to click on the image which normally is done as such: <a href=urlhere><img/></a>.  This will restrict the URL to the image.  However, if you center the image with the center-block class, the URL can then be clicked from anywhere inside of the container.  I want it to be just clickable from the image.

Comment: Not related to answer but try using `href="http://www.apple.com"` instead of `href="www.apple.com"`. This way the click won't take you to the image source or take you to that url inside your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping another element around your `<a>` and `<img>` tags and explicitly centering it via `text-align: center;` or Bootstrap's `text-center` class :

```
<section class="container">
  <!-- You can use Bootstrap's text-center class a style="text-align: center;" here -->
  <div class='center-block text-center'>
    <a href="www.apple.com">
      <img src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201605191653" width="150px;" height="100px;"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Centered Apple Logo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class='center-block text-center'>
      <a href="www.apple.com">
        <img src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201605191653" width="150px;" height="100px;" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I didn't think to just wrap the link and the image inside of the center-block and text-center class.

Comment: How do I get the same effect with the img-responsive tag?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a container for your image and link to sit inside besides just a section tag. In This way you don't have to modify the container class and you introduce a div to organize and style as you wish. Here is the working code:

```
<section class="container">
<div style="width:150px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
  <a class="center-block"href="www.apple.com">
    <img class="center-block" src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201605191653" width="150px;" height="100px;"/>
  </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The link is an inline element so just use `text-center` on the container instead..

```
<section class="container text-center">
  <a href="//www.apple.com">
    <img class="center-block" src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/open_graph_logo.png?201605191653" width="150px;" height="100px;"/>
  </a>
</section>
```

http://codeply.com/go/bLOmNY1pQZ

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the link, as in hovering over any section of the .container will activate the link, rather than just the image, here's the solution:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.container a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This basically gives the link its own dimensions, so it doesn't stretch to fill the parent.